# Using column names in orderBy clause in querydsl

Tags: querydsl

I'm wondering if there is a way to use column names in orderBy clause in querydsl JPA. I want to build multiple `orderBy` conditions from column names coming from the external input.

Let's say I have entity `Person` and column names to sort. I want to do something like code below.

```java
List<String> sortingColumns = ...; // comes from external.
QPerson person = QPerson.person;
JPAQuery<Person> query = jpaQueryFactory.select(person).from(person);
for (String column : sortingColumns) {
    // Is there something like person.getPath(column) in querydsl?
    query = query.orderBy(person.getPath(column).asc());
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [ExpressionUtils.path](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.4/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/ExpressionUtils.html#path-java.lang.Class-com.querydsl.core.types.Path-java.lang.String-)

You have to know the column type to use it. So you need something like this `Map<String, Class<?>> propertyTypeMap = new LinkedHashMap<>()` instead of `List<String> sortingColumns = ...`

```
List<OrderSpecifier> orderBy = new LinkedList<>();

for (Entry<String, Class<?>> entry: propertyTypeMap.entrySet()) {
    String property = entry.getKey();
    Class<?> type = entry.getValue();
    
    orderBy.add(ExpressionUtils.path(type, person, property).asc()); 
}

query.orderBy(
   orderBy.toArray(new OrderSpecifier[orderBy.size()])
);
```

Comment: Hi Alex, what I want to know is if there is some API such as `person.getPath(column)`.

Comment: I ended up using querydsl as a JPA extension (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.4.7/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl). But thank you Alex for answering my question :)

Comment: Using this i get `The method orderBy(OrderSpecifier<?>) in the type QueryBase<JPAQuery<Person>> is not applicable for the arguments (Object[])`

Comment: @jared Try to use this `orderBy.toArray(new OrderSpecifier[orderBy.size()])` for list to array convertation

Comment: @OleksiiValuiskyi I ended up with your first suggestion, just using orderBy did not work.